# On criteria for characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

$1/(1+|t|)$ is a characteristic function by Polya's criterion. I am trying to find out the nature of the distribution function with this characteristic function. Since $1/(1+|t|)$ is not integrable I cannot use the inversion formula to conclude that the distribution function is absolutely continuous. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up Linnik's distribution.